# Can't access action methods inside areas

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've a action method Index inside UserController inside admin area as below:

[image]

My angular code is:

```
var app = angular.module('myAppS', []);

app.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.myVal = "Hello Angular JS";
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        alert('Hi');
        $http.get('/Admin/User/Index').then(function (response) {
            $scope.MyValue = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

my html code is:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

        {{myVal}}

        <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="myFunc()" width="45%" />

</div>
```

When I click get button only alert function gets executed but I cannot make call to server.

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot call the server? `$http.get()` is being invoked. Is there an error in the console? What shows up in the dev tools under the network tab? Is the call being made?

Comment: Could you please provide the error that you see, when your code tried to make a http request from Dev console

Comment: but I cannot make call to server. what do you mean by that

Comment: can you show action which you are trying to access?

Comment: This is the action i am trying to invoke
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var emp = _db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
            return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Cannot make call to server I mean in my angular code
only alert is working and below of that $http.get is not working and it doesn;t invoke the above action method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$http.get('/Admin/User/Index').then(function(response) 
{
     $scope.MyValue = response.data;
}, function(error) 
{
console.log(error);
  console.log("You should get the error here")
});
```

Use this code by itself to see if the $http.get(..) works, then you can put it into myfunc